# selenium xpath, how to select last matching element in a table?

Tags: selenium

Given

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>service1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>service2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>service3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>blip</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How can I select the last 'service-n' row when I don't know what n will be?
I have tried adding `[last()]` but it didn't work.

I have:

```
//table//tr//td[contains(text(),'service')]
```

but it selects the 1st row and I want the last one.
I can't use `tr[3]` because in reality the number of 'service-n' rows is dynamic and changes a lot.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer was exactly where I put the [last()] and I had it in the wrong place

It goes here:

```
//div[@id='content']//table//tr[last()]//td[contains(text(),'service')][last()]/following-sibling::td[2]
```

Not here:

```
//div[@id='content']//table//tr[last()]//td[contains(text(),'service')]/following-sibling::td[2][last()]
```

Answer (score 2):

try with cssSelector, this way.

```
By.cssSelector("table tr:last-child td")
```

Answer (score 1):

```cs
List<WebElement> allElement=fd.findElements(By.xpath("//table//td[contains(.,'service')]");
int count=allElement.size();
allElement.get(count-1).click();
```

Comment: Hi Suresh Shaw; your code might be correct, but with some context it would make a better answer; for example, you could explain how and why this proposed change would resolve the questioner's problem, perhaps including a link to the relevant documentation. That would make it more useful to them, and also more useful to other site readers who are looking for solutions to similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

```
<table id="table1">
 <tbody>
  <tr id="tr1">
   <td id="td1"></td>
   <td id="td2"></td>
  <tr>
  <tr id="tr2">
   <td id="td3"></td>
   <td id="td4"></td>
  <tr>
 <tbody>
</table>
```

Then to target last td of last tr
we can have xpath as:xpath="//table[@id='table1']//tr[last()]//td[last()]";

Answer (score 0):

```
(//div[@id='name'])[last()]
```

By using we can get **the last** element of the relevant filed.

```
//div[@id='name'][last()]
```

Multiple elements in last

Answer (score 0):

```
(//div[contains(@id , "b" )])[last()]
```

For Example :-

if `//div[@id = "abc"]`  is giving `10` elements ,

We want to select 4th element we have to give ,

```
(//div[@id = "abc"])[4]
```

Similarly for last element

```
(//div[@id = "abc"])[last()]
```

Format

```
(Xpath)[last()]
```