# How to select last element in Selenium Webdriver using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriver

I create a script to verify that an element is successfully added. The added element always at the end of the page or become last element in different div. I am using selenium webdriver and javascript. Here's HTML code

```
<div class="row">
<div class="form-group col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
        <label>Entity Name</label>
        <input value="ttax" class="form-control entity-name" disabled="">
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="form-group col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
       <label>Entity Name</label>
       <input value="Room" class="form-control entity-name" disabled="">
</div>
</div>
```

I tried this

```
let new_entity = await driver.findElement(By.css("div:nth-child(2) > div.form-group.col-sm-2.col-xs-12 > input").last()
let entity_value = await new_entity.getAttribute('value')
expect(entity_value).to.be.eq(entity_name)
```

But I got error
`element.last() is not function`

Can anyone help me? I can not find references about selenium webdriver in javascript, most of them using java. [ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YW18H.png)

Comment: Already we have post on the same issue please find it here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15788679/selenium-xpath-how-to-select-last-matching-element-in-a-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the added element always becomes the last element to verify the added element you need to locate the `last-child` of the *parent element* which you haven't shown us in the HTML within the question. So to locate the `last-child` you can use the following [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors) based [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *css*:

  ```
  let new_entity = await driver.findElement(By.css("immediateParentTag div:last-child > div.form-group.col-sm-2.col-xs-12 > input"))
  ```

Comment: I still can not get the last element, I got first element, I want to get 'Room'. I attached the snippet code on my post

Comment: Instead of the image can you update the question with the text based HTML?

Comment: You need to provide the HTML of the first element which you don't want so we can adjust the locator, preferably along with the parent element.

Comment: html of 1st element added

Comment: @herawatimanurung Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: solved using ```let entity_last_block = await driver.findElement(By.css('div.card.card-entity:last-child'))``` as parent. Thanks, debanjanB

Answer (score 0):

Here when you want to use the last or first element then we have to get an element array. Instead of findElement, we can use findElements

```
let new_entity = await driver.findElements(By.css("..")).last();
```

let entity_value = await new_entity.getAttribute('value');
expect(entity_value).to.be.eq(entity_name);

Comment: I tried using yours but got error ```InvalidSelectorError: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified```